# Conver Type class to a generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, types

Lets say I have a function

```
public void func1<T>();
```

And another function:

```
public void func2(Type type);
```

Inside func2, I want to call func1 with type. how can I "Convert" the type so it can fit in?

edit:
I didn't thought it will matter, but func1 is not my function. it part of the framework:

```
context.CreateObjectSet<T>()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call the generic function explicitly because you do not know the type at compile time. You can use reflections to call `func1` and specify your `type` as generic argument. However I would advise you to change the signature of the methods to avoid using reflections if possible.

Here is an example of how to do it with Reflections:

```
    private static void Method1(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Method2", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    private static void Method2<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
    }
```

Comment: Can you make your func2 generic? If not then you cannot call func1 without reflections - you do not know the type that will be passed to func1 as generic parameter at compile time and generics are about knowing the type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use reflection.

```
public void func2(Type type)
{
    // call func1<T>()
    var thisType = this.GetType();
    var method = thisType.GetMethod("func1", new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod(type);
    method.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, of course: you can simply go the other direction and make the `Type` version the "real" one:

```
public T func1<T>() 
{
    func2(typeof(T));
}

public object func2(Type type)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```

This is similar to how the framework implements `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>` and `Enum.TryParseEnum`.  The implementation of the generic `TEnum` variant simply passes it along (via `typeof(TEnum)`) to the non-generic (`Type`-based) method.